# MVC 5 Validation Error messages not appearing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem where the validation messages are not appearing for a given form. The form appears inside a jQuery modal dialog, which is opened when you click a button on the main page.

When I try submitting the form with all fields empty, I should get errors that such and such fields are required, but I don't. However, if I debug and go into the Controller code to see what Model is being reported as invalid, I see the messages mentioned here, that such and such fields are required.

I have tried removing the custom JavaScript being used in the view when Submit is done, but that doesn't solve the problem.

This is the model:

```
public class Expense : ActivityLog
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public bool chargedBySeller { get; set; }
        public string chargingEntity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string chargeCurrency { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double chargeAmount { get; set; }
        public DateTime chargeDate { get; set; }
        public bool countInExpensesTotalling { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string paymentMethod { get; set; }
        public List<Refund> refundsDoneForThisCharge { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the controller:

```
public class PurchasesController : Controller
{
    private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();

    //Other Actions removed for brevity


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrEditExpense(Expense expense)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Session["expensesList"] == null)
            {
                Session["expensesList"] = new List<Expense>();
            }

            if ((int)Session["expenseAddEditMode"] == 2) //ADD
            {
                ((List<Expense>)Session["expensesList"]).Add(expense);
            }
            else if ((int)Session["expenseAddEditMode"] == 1) //EDIT
            {
                ((List<Expense>)Session["expensesList"])[(int)Session["expenseEditIndex"]] = expense;
            }
        }

        return PartialView("~/Views/Purchases/Expense/ViewList.cshtml", Session["expensesList"]);
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the Razor View code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#add-or-edit-expense-form").on("submit", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#expense-list-div").html(data);
                    $("#expense-dialog").dialog("close");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


@model ExpOrderBluManagement_Web.Models.ApplicationModels.Expense

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEditExpense", "Purchases", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "add-or-edit-expense-form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Expense</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chargedBySeller, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chargedBySeller)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chargedBySeller, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chargingEntity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chargingEntity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chargingEntity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chargeCurrency, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chargeCurrency, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chargeCurrency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chargeAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chargeAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chargeAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chargeDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chargeDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chargeDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.countInExpensesTotalling, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.countInExpensesTotalling)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.countInExpensesTotalling, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.paymentMethod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.paymentMethod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.paymentMethod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: have checked ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in apseeting?

Comment: How do you load your partial view? Via ajax or by @Html.Partial?
Try with this: http://code.davidferguson.me.uk/post/47540738095/mvc-client-validation-after-partialview-loaded-via

Comment: jquery.validate.unobtrusive parses the form when it is first loaded. If you dynamically add controls to the DOM, you need to reparse the validator

Comment: If a Model.IsValid Fails, why do you return Session["expenselist"]? I think you should do this: return PartialView("~/Views/Purchases/Expense/ViewList.cshtml"", expense); I don't think ModelState is maintained when you return Model from Session like you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Stephen sad if you dynamically add controls to the DOM, you must reparse the validator. Try writing your script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var $form = $("#add-or-edit-expense-form");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);

        $form.on("submit", function (e) {    
            e.preventDefault();
            if($form.valid()) {
              $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#expense-list-div").html(data);
                    $("#expense-dialog").dialog("close");
                }
              });
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

adding this **$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);** Also, I would check if form is valid and then do the ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

You have jQuery Val at bottom of page, do you have a link to jQuery in head

Comment: By default, its always at the bottom of the page. I have other forms elsewhere in my application where its at the bottom, and their validation works fine.